# protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rubygems, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a problem with my ruby selenium-driver script that has been working fine up until recently. I can't think of any changes I've done to my environment that may have stopped it working.

**Here's the code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'capybara'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'pry'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.register_driver :chromedriver do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :chromedriver

class BulkDoAction
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize(file)
    @value_ids = File.readlines file
  end

  def delete(value_id)

    puts "#{Time.now} -> saving value=#{value_id}"
    visit "https://www.url.com/#{value_id}/confirmSave"

    click_button "Save"
    sleep 5.0
  end

  def run
    visit 'https://www.url.com/login'

    fill_in 'Email or Username', with: 'XXX'
    fill_in 'password', with: 'XXX'
    click_button "Login"
    sleep 5.0

    @value_ids.each_with_index do |val_id, idx|
      puts "Doing #{idx + 1} out of #{@value_ids.size}"
      delete val_id.to_i
      sleep 3.0
    end
  end
end

BulkDoAction.new('test.txt').run
```

I've changed a few of the values, as there is sensitive information.

**However, whenever I run this as:**

./bulk.rb

**I get the following exception:**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1377:in `block in request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:103:in `response_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:57:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:653:in `raw_execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:124:in `create_session'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:88:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:40:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:62:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:62:in `for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:82:in `for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:20:in `browser'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:53:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:240:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-2.10.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    from ./bulk.rb:48:in `run'
    from ./bulk.rb:63:in `<main>'
```

I get this when I run both the brew installed ruby, and force running the system ruby which is 2.0.0.

I feel as there's something wrong with my gems and being read the script but I can't figure it out.

**Here is my gem list:**

```
addressable (2.4.0)
archive-zip (0.7.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
capybara (2.10.1)
childprocess (0.5.9)
chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
coderay (1.1.1)
ffi (1.9.14)
io-console (0.4.3)
io-like (0.3.0)
json (1.8.1)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
power_assert (0.2.2)
pry (0.10.4)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (2.0.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.0.0)
slop (3.6.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
webdriver-firefox (0.0.15)
websocket (1.2.3)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

So just to clarify, I'm not even getting to the URL when chrome opens up, it is stuck on 'data;' and then it throws the exception in terminal.

Nothing has changed with the script, so I think it's something to do with my environment.

If anyone has any ideas I would be most grateful while I continue trying to figure it out!

Comment: In my experience rbuf_fill (read buffer filled up) can occur occasionally due to a block in network traffic / ports by ruby processes. A simple machine restart has fixed this for me mostly, so worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't budge though.

I actually re-wrote the whole thing in python now as I got frustrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the same error and I've upgraded chromedriver to version 2.25 (chromedriver_mac64.zip  2016-10-22 06:23:51 4.35MB).

Now, it runs perfectly fine.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads